# flens lapack: GNU GCC Version 4.7 or higher required! my mac has

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, installation, gnu

I was trying a tutorial (http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/FLENS/flens/examples/lapack-geqp3.html) from FLENS-LAPACK.
I have download the src code from the website (https://github.com/michael-lehn/FLENS).

when I try the instruction from the tutorial

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -I../.. -o lapack-geqp3 lapack-geqp3.cc
```

I had error from the console:

> ```
> In file included from lapack-geqp3.cc:2:0:
> ../../flens/flens.cxx:45:6: error: static assertion failed: 
> GNU GCC Version 4.7 or higher required! static_assert(__GNUG__>=4 && __GNUC_MINOR__>=7,
> ```

I checked the gcc version of my mac

```
$ gcc -v  
Using built-in specs. 
COLLECT_GCC=gcc 
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/5.0.0/lto-wrapper Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0 
Configured with: ../gcc-5-20141005/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran Thread model: posix 
gcc version 5.0.0 20141005 (experimental) (GCC)
```

It shows that my mac has gcc 5.0.0.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the gcc on my mac??
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noting is wrong with your GCC, the `static_assert` is wrong.

```
static_assert(__GNUG__>=4 && __GNUC_MINOR__>=7, ...)
```

This checks that GCC is both version 4.x or newer, but *also* minor version 7 or newer. This assertion will only pass on 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 5.7, 5.8, ... etc.

If the assertion is changed like so:

```
static_assert(__GNUG__==4 && __GNUC_MINOR__>=7 || __GNUG__>4, ...)
```

Then it should pass for GCC 5 (assuming it defines `__GNUG__` as 5; I have no way of checking at the moment.)

Edit: I've [submitted a patch](https://github.com/michael-lehn/FLENS/pull/11) to fix this issue, which has already been accepted and merged. If you pull the latest HEAD, your issue should be fixed.